# Evaluating JavaScript in Java with GraalVM

Tags: javascript, java, graalvm

Until now we have used Nashorn to evaluate JS code in our Java project.
Nashorn has couple of known disadvantages and we would like to move to GraalVM.

So we did a small POC and run into couple of issues, i hope you can help us :)

Our business use case:
We provide our users a platform to write custom js code according to the following interface:

```
function process(record, ctx, logger, next) {
   if (record && record.data){
        record.data.firstName = "Joe";
    }
    return record;
}
```

record represents our internal model which is a Java Map.

And we would like to invoke the 'process' function from within our Java code and provide the parameters.

Few questions for you:

1. What is the best way to do it according to the best practices?
   The 'record' parameter is a Java Map object which represent our internal model. when we send it to the process function, we would like it to be handled as a standard js object so our users can write standard js code according to ECMA. What is the right way to do it?
2. We noticed the performance of Nashorn is better than Graalvm when we run couple of tests, is that make sense or we probably do something wrong?

We really appreciate your assistance and would like to move very soon to Graalvm.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using the GraalVM polyglot API Take a look at ProxyObjects (https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/proxy/ProxyObject.html). I think that might be your best bet.
2. The GraalVM JS implementation should definitively outperform Nashorn but may need a couple of iterations of warmup to get there. Did you allow for warmup in your measurements?

Comment: 1. You are right, we started to use the ProxyObject and that do the work :)                 2. How do you recommend to do the warmup? Running 1M iterations is good enough?

Comment: Depends on how you are running them I guess. If it's the same code in the same context it should warm up before that. You can take a look at https://github.com/graalvm/graal-js-jdk11-maven-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java too see one way of doing it. The project in that repo can be run on GraalVM and shows a comparison between GraalVM/JS and Nashorn. Should be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks Boris, we run this benchmark and indeed the Graal run twice faster than Nashorn. However this benchmark doesn't simulate our use case. The way we run scripts is by providing couple of parameters(ProxyObject) and return a value. This way we see the Nasorn has much better performance than Graal. Any idea?

Comment: By the way, here is a sample of the script we are testing:
   function process(record, ctx, logger) {
    if (record && record.profile) {
        record.profile.firstName='NewFirstName';
        // logger.info("rename", "name changed");
    }
    return record;
}

Comment: How many times do you execute the function? Notice that the example I shared executes the benchmark 10 times (warmup) and than starts measuring the performance. If you do something similar and still have worse performance than Nashorn you might wanna file an issue https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/issues .

Comment: We run it 1M times

Comment: Best submit an issue, this should not be happening. If possible, share the minimal code needed to recreate your results.